# Is there a java lambda expression equivalent of the C# linq let?

Tags: java, c#, linq, lambda, java-8

Is there a java 8 lambda expression equivalent of the let setting? For instance, how would I write this c# linq expression using Java 8 lambda expressions?

```
String[] lines = new String[]{"Porky.Pig", "Darth.Vader", "Donald.Duck", "George Lucas"};
(from l in lines      
 let p = l.IndexOf('.')
 where p >= 0
 select new
 {
     FirstName = l.Substring(0, p),
     LastName = l.Substring(p + 1)
 }).Dump();
```

I want to evaluate l.IndexOf('.') only once. The closest I came up with is:

```
 String[] lines = new String[]{"Porky.Pig", "Darth.Vader", "Donald.Duck", "George Lucas"};
 Arrays.stream(lines)
       .filter(x -> x.indexOf('.') > 0)
       .map(x -> {
           int p = x.indexOf('.');
           return new Person (x.substring(0, p), x.substring( p + 1));
       });
```

where:

```
public class Person {
    public Person(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
    }
}
```

ok, based on the suggestion in the Shlomi Borovitz's answer I came up with this which makes use of this [Pair](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html) class

```
String[] lines = new String[]{"Porky.Pig", "Darth.Vader", "Donald.Duck", "George Lucas"};
Arrays.stream(lines)
      .map(x -> Pair.of(x, x.indexOf('.')))
      .filter(x -> x.getRight() > 0)
      .map(x -> new Person (x.getLeft().substring(0, x.getRight()), x.getLeft().substring( x.getRight()  + 1)));
```

Comment: That's not a lambda expression, that's LINQ syntax query.

Comment: `let` just converted to a call to `Select`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek But since Java doesn't have LINQ keywords, he'd need it to be a lambda which provides the same functionality

Comment: The above query would be converted to `lines.Select(l => new {l, p = l.IndexOf('.') }).Where(_ => _.p >= 0).Select(_ => new { FirstName = _.lSubString(0, _.p), LastName = _.l.SubString(_.p + 1)`

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz: I've been using the c# linq queries for a few years and now I am having a bit of hard time going to java 8 lambda expressions. There seems to be no Java equivalent of the C# anonymous classes (created with new {...}). I thought of using tuples.

Comment: @costa , I do not familiar with java. Tuple are sound like a good idea if there are no better solutions. :/

Comment: @costa I believe that you want to ask if there is a better solution than the `Pair` class. I hope I'm not mistaking :)

Comment: May I suggest to use `.split("\\.", 2)` method and use the output `String[]` for further steps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linq query in C# is converted to "dot syntaxt" (which is regular method calls):
The query:

```
from l in lines      
let p = l.IndexOf('.')
where p >= 0
select new 
{
    FirstName = l.Substring(0, p), 
    LastName = l.Substring(p + 1)
}
```

is converted to something like this:

```
lines.Select(l => new {l, p = l.IndexOf('.') })
     .Where(_ => _.p >= 0)
     .Select(_ => new 
         { 
             FirstName = _.l.SubString(0, _.p), 
             LastName = _.l.SubString(_.p + 1) 
         })
```

Figure out how to do that in Java.

If there is no equivalent to C#'s anonymous types, tuples are a good idea, where the usage isn't justifying creating another class.

Answer (score 6):

The absence of tuples certainly is a problem. But if we use the declaration of `Person` in the question and take up @Ulugbek Umirov's suggestion of using `String.split`, this is a reasonably neat solution:

```
List<Person> persons = Arrays.stream(lines)
    .map(s -> s.split("\\."))
    .filter(arr -> arr.length > 1)
    .map(arr -> new Person(arr[0], arr[1]))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Not being sure what `Dump` does, I've arbitrarily chosen to collect the `Person` objects into a `List`.

Comment: Dump is a method supported by linqpad (linqpad is a very nice utility for running c# code snippets: https://www.linqpad.net/)